# Socket Programming: Setup server, it runs if port is 80, but cannot run if port is other

Tags: sockets, websocket, localhost, webserver, serversocket

I'm trying to setup a server using Python socket programming, using the code below:

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 80
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(("", serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print ("The server is ready to receive")

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
    connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence.encode())
    connectionSocket.close()
```

When I use this code and try to enter `localhost` in a web browser, I get the response without any problem as shown.

[image: browser window if port is 80]

But, when I change line 3 in the code to `serverPort = 12000` and try to enter `localhost:12000`, I don't get a response.

[image: browser window if port is not 80]

Note: I use Windows not Linux, and I run the Python code on PyCharm 2020.3.3.

Comment: Don't post links here, or pictures of text. Post the text.

Comment: I just tried to explain the problem in the best way.. I'll use text in the next time

Answer (score 0):

Neither example should be working, regardless of the port used, because the server is not sending back a valid HTTP response, like the error message says. The fact that the 1st example "works" is a fluke.

Try this instead:

```py
from socket import *

serverPort = 80
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(("", serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print ("The server is ready to receive")

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
    capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
    reply = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
    connectionSocket.send(reply.encode()) # <-- add this!
    connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence.encode())
    connectionSocket.close()
```